# Angular 4 form properties for routed child components not available when view rendered

Tags: angular

We are creating a small Angular app poc (angular 4.2.4, bootrap 4.0.0-beta2, ng-bootstrap 1.0.0-beta6, typescript 2.3.3).

The app is to display user data in template-driven forms.  Routing is set up so that the parent component loads by default when navigating to localhost:4200.  This parent component has a side-nav child component, and a content area with a `<router-outlet>` where child components get displayed depending on the selection made on the side-nav - pretty simple (see code snippets below).  Each child component should display
a specific section of the user data in a form.

When the application starts, the parent's `ngOnInit` method uses a service to call an endpoint to retrieve all the user data in one fell swoop.  This all works fine - the service is modeled somewhat after the angular tour-of-heros service, and we
have experience with this.  I also want to use a shared service to keep this retrieved User around, so that the child components do not have to get it each time they are displayed.  I've provided this shared service once in the app's `@NgModule`.  When the first child component is created to be displayed in the parent's content area, it's own `ngOnInit` is called, in which I attempt to retrieve the User object that I had just put on the service when the parent's `ngOnInit` was called.

parent template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <user-sidenav></user-sidenav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

parent ngOnInit:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.userService.getUser(1)
            .then(user => this.userService.currentUser = user);
  }
```

child ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = this.userService.currentUser;
  }
```

I believe I recognize what's happening.  It seems like expected behavior code-wise, but I don't know how to resolve.  Please correct me if wrong.  Since the parent's `ngOnInit` is working to resolve a promise, retrieving the User and putting it on the service is an async operation.  The `ngOnInit` finishes and moves on while its promise code is  executing.  Meanwhile, and very quickly, the child component's `ngOnInit` is called since it is the default child route of the parent.  It expects the User object to be available on the service, and tries to retrieve it.  Since I'm getting undefined object errors, it looks to me like although the parent's `ngOnInit` has completed, the async promise code has not finished putting the User object on the service - hence the undefined data and errors.

Right now my service is not using "the Angular way" of using a Subject to handle the shared data.  I did have it that way at first, but I didn't think it was needed for what we are doing, and it didn't make a difference anyway.  Also, I've seen where Resolvers can be used to make sure data is defined before routes are activated, but I was reluctant to go down that path before hearing from  Stackoverflow because it seems like I'd need a different Resolver for each child route - not sure, though.  Otherwise, it seems like I might need to retrieve the data in the `ngOnInit` method of each child component, something I felt like using a shared service would help me avoid.

What is the best or preferred way to ensure the child component property values are set before its page is rendered?

Comment: Use a resolve on the parent route to load the user data. In the parent component, store the user, found in the ActivatedRoute, in the service. In general, especially if you don't master observables, everything becomes much simpler when using resolves.

Comment: @JBNizet - This worked!  Thanks much.  Good to see I only need to add the resolve for the parent - one and done.  As an aside, should this be done somehow without a resolve?  I've read in a couple places not to overuse resolves.  I don't know if this case would qualify as overusing, but it worked and was slick.  BTW, using the resolve also allowed me to deep-6 this nasty syntax in the template:

[ngModel]="currentAddress?.city" (ngModelChange)="........ and get back to the 2-way binding syntax [(ngModel)]=....

Comment: BTW for anyone else struggling with this issue, here is a link to a blog that helped me implement @JBNizet's suggestion:

[https://shermandigital.com/blog/wait-for-data-before-rendering-views-in-angular-2/]

Comment: I really like resolves in general. They make a whole lot of things easier. If the backend is not slow to respond, using one is fine to me. Regarding your ngModel problem, a cleaner, simpler way to fix that (when not using a resolve) would simply be to have an ngIf on your form to only display it once the user data is available in the component.